# How to use the htmlWrapper in Flex4?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

How to use htmlWrapper in Flex4?

Answer (score 2):

How do you code your flex applications? If you use Flex Builder, it's automatically generated.
Otherwise, there are also a ANT task and a FlexMojos goal.

If you want to create it manually from scratch, look at the official documentation : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ba8.html